# Why react Dropdown component need pass the data to a const variable or it could not be rendered

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to react. Rencently I met a condition that the drop down component could not directly render the data that we passed into.

My component code:

```
function PackageSelection({data, switchPackage}) {
  const items = data
  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size={16}>
      <Dropdown
        menu={{
          items,
        }}
        trigger={['click']}
        arrow={{pointAtCenter: true}}
      >
      </Dropdown>
    </Space>
  )

}
```

I found if we do not have this code "const items = data", component would be rendered failed. For now, I could not figured out why?

The data passed-into is:

```
[
    {
        "key": "official",
        "type": "group",
        "label": "official item",
        "children": [
            {
                "key": "01.00.00.01_official",
                "label": "01.00.00.01"
            },
            {
                "key": "01.00.00.02_official",
                "label": "01.00.00.02"
            },
          ]
     }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no difference between:

```js
function PackageSelection({data, switchPackage}) {
  const items = data
  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size={16}>
      <Dropdown
        menu={{
          items,
        }}
        trigger={['click']}
        arrow={{pointAtCenter: true}}
      >
      </Dropdown>
    </Space>
  )
}
```

and:

```js
function PackageSelection({data, switchPackage}) {
  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size={16}>
      <Dropdown
        menu={{
          data,
        }}
        trigger={['click']}
        arrow={{pointAtCenter: true}}
      >
      </Dropdown>
    </Space>
  )

}
```

The only explanation I can think of is that the property of the object passed to `menu` should be called `items`

---

In javaScript

```js
{
foo,
}
```

is the same as :

```js
{
foo: foo
}
```

so if you try:

```js
function PackageSelection({data, switchPackage}) {
  return (
    <Space direction="vertical" size={16}>
      <Dropdown
        menu={{
          items: data,
        }}
        trigger={['click']}
        arrow={{pointAtCenter: true}}
      >
      </Dropdown>
    </Space>
  )
}
```

it should work.

Comment: The explanation, "The only explanation I can think of is that the property of the object passed to menu should be called items" saved my life, thank you very much. It is correct, the  drop-down component requests key items. Thanks again, it gives me more perspective about javascript.

Comment: I will vote the answer while my reputation is more than 15.